# ScriptIgnore tag being ignored even with ApplyToOverrides = true... and it works in LinqPad

Tags: c#, entity-framework, javascriptserializer

Basically, I'm trying to send a simple entity into json using JavaScriptSerializer.  Yes, I know you want me to make a redundant class for that and shove it through AutoMapper and I'm asking for trouble.  Humour me.

I'm using Entity Framework 6 to fetch a simple object to fetch a simple object.

Here's my test code:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestEntityTest()
    {
        var db = new TestDbContext();
        var ent = db.ResupplyForms.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Guid == new Guid("55117161-F3FA-4291-8E9B-A67F3B416097"));
        var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ent);
    }
```

Pretty straight forward.  Fetch the thing and serialize it.

It errors out with the following:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Extensions.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ResupplyForm_13763C1B587B4145B35C75CE2D5394EBED19F93943F42503204F91E0B9B4294D'.
```

Here's the entity:

```C#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;
using Rome.Model.DataDictionary;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace Rome.Model.Form
{
    [Table(nameof(ResupplyForm))]
    public partial class ResupplyForm
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ResupplyFormID {get;set;}

        public Guid Guid {get;set;}

        public int? RecordStatus {get;set;}

        [ForeignKey(nameof(RecordStatus))]
        [ScriptIgnore(ApplyToOverrides = true)]
        public virtual LookupItem RecordStatusLookupItem {get;set;} 
    }
}
```

I'll leave out the def for LookupItem because that gets into the schema of the whole rest of my project and there's no sane world in which that should matter, since I already flagged it as "ignored".

And here's a super-simple context:

```C#
public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
    public TestDbContext()
        : base("data source=.;initial catalog=studybaseline;integrated security=True;pooling=False;multipleactiveresultsets=False")
    {

    }

    public virtual DbSet<ResupplyForm> ResupplyForms { get; set; }
}
```

And now, the coup de gras: A LinqPad query that runs perfectly, using the exact same code as my snippet:

```
var db = new Rome.Model.Form.TestDbContext();
var ent = db.ResupplyForms.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Guid == new Guid("55117161-F3FA-4291-8E9B-A67F3B416097"));
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ent).Dump();
```

Which happily returns

```
{"ResupplyFormID":1,"Guid":"55117161-f3fa-4291-8e9b-a67f3b416097","RecordStatus":null}
```

I have been pulling my hair out all day on this one, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've dug further into this a day later and found the cause: it has *nothing* to do with the `[ScriptIgnore(ApplyToOverrides = true)]` things.  It has to do with the EntityProxy subclass that Entity Framework creates for every entity.  My ResupplyForm isn't actually used as a ResupplyForm in my tests... instead it's an EntityProxy subclass.

This EntityProxy subclass adds a new member, _entityWrapper.  If the EntityProxy is wrapping a class with no navigational properties, _entityWrapper doesn't contain any cycles... but as soon as you add a navigational property, the _entityWrapper contains cycles, which breaks serialization.

Vague error messages ruin everything.  If the JavaScriptSerializer told me which field was bad, I could've saved a lot of time.

Anyhow, I should look at switching to NewtonSoft, but that's created its own problems (for another post) but instead I've created a *very* crude workaround:

```
public static class JsonSerializerExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Convert entity to JSON without blowing up on cyclic reference.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="target">The object to serialize</param>
        /// <param name="entityTypes">Any entity-framework-related types that might be involved in this serialization.  If null, it will only use the type of "target".</param>
        /// <param name="ignoreNulls">Whether nulls should be serialized or not.</param>
        /// <returns>Json</returns>
        /// <remarks>This requires some explanation: all POCOs used by entites aren't their true form.  
        /// They're subclassed proxies of the object you *think* you're defining.  These add a new member
        /// _EntityWrapper, which contains cyclic references that break the javascript serializer.
        /// This is Json Serializer function that skips _EntityWrapper for any type in the entityTypes list.
        /// If you've a complicated result object that *contains* entities, forward-declare them with entityTypes.
        /// If you're just serializing one object, you can omit entityTypes.
        ///</remarks>
        public static string ToJsonString(this object target, IEnumerable<Type> entityTypes = null, bool ignoreNulls = true)
        {
            var javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            if(entityTypes == null)
            {
                entityTypes = new[] { target.GetType() };
            }
            javaScriptSerializer.RegisterConverters(new[] { new EntityProxyConverter(entityTypes, ignoreNulls) });
            return javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(target);
        }
    }

    public class EntityProxyConverter : JavaScriptConverter
    {
        IEnumerable<Type> _EntityTypes = null;
        bool _IgnoreNulls;
        public EntityProxyConverter(IEnumerable<Type> entityTypes, bool ignoreNulls = true) : base()
        {
            _EntityTypes = entityTypes;
            _IgnoreNulls = ignoreNulls;
        }

        public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
        {
            get
            {
                return _EntityTypes;
            }
        }

        public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
        {
            var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            if (obj == null)
            {
                return result;
            }
            var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties(
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public 
                | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance 
                | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty
            );
            foreach (var propertyInfo in properties.Where(p => Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(p, typeof(ScriptIgnoreAttribute), true).Length == 0))
            {
                if (!propertyInfo.Name.StartsWith("_"))
                {
                    var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
                    if (value != null || !_IgnoreNulls)
                    {
                        result.Add(propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null));
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

You have to pass in the classes (which, let's remember, are on-the-fly generated proxy classes) to use it, sadly, so it will probably fail miserably for any reasonable object-graph, but it will work for simple single objects and arrays and the like.  It also fails for use with JsonResult because these overrides can't be used there.